# How to declare a function that receives a class of an Object with bounds

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'd like a function that receives a class derived from an Activity.

Here is my first attempt that doesn't compile:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

fun a(c: KClass<*: CharSequence>) = c.java.name

fun main() {
    println(a(""::class))
}
```

I've read this before asking: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html

If it were `Scala`, I could use this syntax:

```
def a(c: Class[_ <: CharSequence]) = c.getClass.name
```

Comment: You should read that article again. It has the answer you're looking for, and at no point does it suggest a `<*: Type>` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Article you mentioned actually answers your question. Let's find the answer in it!

First, the article explains different types of variance. It says type parameters could be **invariant**, **covariant** or **contravariant**. As Kotlin users often have some background in Java or other JVM languages, and they could know the concept of variance already, the article explains the topic by referencing the syntax specific to Java. It says:

> The wildcard type argument `<? extends E>` indicates that this method accepts a collection of objects of `E` or a subtype of `E`, not just `E` itself. (...) In other words, the wildcard with an extends-bound (upper bound) makes the type **covariant**.

This is exactly what we are looking for! We need to accept subtypes of the `CharSequence`, not only the `CharSequence` itself.

Now, let's find how to accomplish the same in Kotlin:

> To fix this, you should declare objects of type `Source<? extends Object>`. (...) In Kotlin, there is a way to explain this sort of thing to the compiler. (...) To do this, use the **`out`** modifier.

> The **`out`** modifier is called a variance annotation, and since it is provided at the type parameter declaration site, it provides declaration-site variance. This is in contrast with Java's use-site variance where wildcards in the type usages make the types **covariant**.

As we can see, we need to use a **covariant** type. In Java, we declare covariant types with: `? extends Number`, in Kotlin we do: `out Number`. Now we know the answer:

```kotlin
fun a(c: KClass<out CharSequence>) = c.java.name
```

Article may seem a little complicated, because variance in Kotlin isn't 1:1 the same as in Java. Different syntax is one thing, but Kotlin also introduces declaration-site variance. Additionally, while variance in Java focuses on extending/"supering", Kotlin variance focuses on producing/consuming which is just another perspective on the same problem. Article explains all these matters at once, so it may be confusing to some readers. It doesn't provide a simple answer: `? extends` => `out`, because that wouldn't be 100% accurate.

Comment: I come from a Scala background, and it also has the (co)variance concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right syntax:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
   
fun <T: CharSequence> a(c: KClass<T>) = 
   c.java.name
   
fun main() {
   println(a(""::class)) 
}
```

In Scala there is no need to declare the function as generic, only the parameter.

Comment: What do you suppose is the right syntax?

Comment: It was wrong because when you didn't have it formatted as code, the uses of `<` and `>` didn't appear.